# Python Web-Scraping Code only returning first iteration in my loop

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web-scraping. I wrote a code to return the header, paragraph, and youtube link of article within the webpage. My "for" loop is returning the first iteration correctly, but it's repeating it 10 times and not pulling the other articles. There are 10 separate articles on the webpage so I think it has something to do with the .select function I'm writing. Code below:

```
import requests
import bs4


url = 'https://coreyms.com'

    # Get the url in a response object and make sure it runs correctly

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

    # Now im using bs4 to parse all the html into a single string on the webpage 

schafer = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Attempting to use a for loop  
    
for article in schafer.find_all('article'):
    header = schafer.select('article a')
    header = header[0].getText()
    print(header)

    paragraph = schafer.select('article div > p')
    paragraph = paragraph[0].getText()
    print(paragraph)
    
    link = schafer.select('article iframe')

    #     This is where you parse out the youtube link to just get the pure link to watch on Youtube

    link = link[0].get('src')
    vidID = link.split('/')[4]
    vidID = vidID.split('?')[0]
    ytLink = f'https://youtube.com/watch?v={vidID}'
    print(ytLink)
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

You use this as your iterator:

```
for article in schafer.find_all('article'):
```

So the variable that changes every loop is `article`. However, you never use this variable, instead using `schafer`, which is a variable that never changes as the loops go on.

To fix you problem, replace `schafer` with `article` and change the `select` statement. For example:

```
header = schafer.select('article a')
```

becomes

```
header = article.select('a')
```

The line

```
paragraph = schafer.select('article div > p')
```

becomes

```
paragraph = article.select('div > p')
```

You should then get the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like the below

```
import requests
import bs4

response = requests.get(url='https://coreyms.com')

schafer = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for article in schafer.find_all('article'):
    header = article.findNext('h2').text
    print(f"Header: {header}")
    paragraph = article.findNext('div', class_="entry-content").text
    print(f"Paragraph: {paragraph}")
    yt_link = article.findNext('iframe', class_="youtube-player")['src'].split('?')[0].replace("embed/", "watch?v=")
    print(f"YouTube Link: {yt_link}")
```

Comment: This looks like a far more efficient code than the one I wrote. Thank you!